# File Upload in Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am unable to upload my file upload program. I created a small project in django to upload and download files. This project was/is working very fine. Now i am trying this in Mezzanine for which i have created following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
from time import time

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "galleries/%s_%s" %(str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)


GENDER = (('----','Please Select ...'),('male','Male'), ('female','Female'))
class AllUsers(models.Model):
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    DOB = models.DateField()
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices = GENDER)
    HomeAddress = models.TextField()
    Contact = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Email = models.EmailField()
    CV = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)
```

forms like :

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AllUsers
        fields = ['FullName' ,'DOB' ,'Gender','HomeAddress','Contact','Email','CV','UserDepartment']
```

Html page for form

```
<form action="/users/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token%}
     <fieldset>
        {{id}}
    <legend>Users Profile</legend>
    {% fields_for form %}
    <div class="form-actions">
        {% block account_form_actions %}
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" type="submit" value="Submit">
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Problem: I upload my file and press submit button, on submission it moves me to html form page and remove the file i uploaded. and ask me to upload file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not deleting this question, because this may help!

Your forms do not upload files. No worries. See:

**SYMPTOM**
You have FileField() and ImageField() fields in your form and the files are not uploaded when you submit this form

**PROBABLE CAUSE**
You might be missing the request.FILES argument when intantiate your Form object.

**SOLUTION**
Always make sure that you are passing request.FILES when intantiate your Form object:

form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

***More Details : *** https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes